# Type mismatch in excel vba when appending to a cell

Tags: excel, vba, scripting

Im trying to append some text to each of the header columns in my excel document with a vba script.

```
Dim c As Range

For Each c In Sheet13.Rows(1)
    c.Value = c.Value & "bleh"
Next
```

However this is giving me a type mismatch error 13 and i dont know why. 
The cells just contain text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
For Each c In Sheet13.UsedRange.Rows(1).Cells
```

`.Cells` to get individual cells, not entire rows.

`.UsedRange` to avoid going to the end of the row (`XFD1`). You can tweak it to get only non-empty, constant cells, i.e.:

```
For Each c In Sheet13.UsedRange.Rows(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
```

Comment: Excellent thanks. Ill mark it correct when the timer runs out.

Answer (score 2):

Try the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddBleh()

Dim c As Range
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim HeaderRng As Range

With Sheet13
    ' find last column with data in header row
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    ' set Range to only header row where there is data
    Set HeaderRng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, LastCol))

    For Each c In HeaderRng.Cells
        c.Value = c.Value & "bleh"
    Next

End With

End Sub
```